# How to prevent session not to reset when user login on checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, session, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have some session values on checkout page that i'm sending as email to customer as well as adding in order details too. The problem is that when user logged in and going to checkout everything is working fine, but when user trying to logged in on checkout page, session get reset and we got blank value as session. I don't want to  reset session values when user login on checkout page. My functions.php file is as following

```
  <?php
/**
 * Twenty Seventeen functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 */

/**
 * Twenty Seventeen only works in WordPress 4.7 or later.
 */
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '4.7-alpha', '<' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/back-compat.php';
    return;
}

/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
 * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
 * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
 */
function twentyseventeen_setup() {
    /*
     * Make theme available for translation.
     * Translations can be filed at WordPress.org. See: https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-themes/twentyseventeen
     * If you're building a theme based on Twenty Seventeen, use a find and replace
     * to change 'twentyseventeen' to the name of your theme in all the template files.
     */
    load_theme_textdomain( 'twentyseventeen' );

    // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    /*
     * Let WordPress manage the document title.
     * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
     * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
     * provide it for us.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
     *
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    add_image_size( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image', 2000, 1200, true );

    add_image_size( 'twentyseventeen-thumbnail-avatar', 100, 100, true );

    // Set the default content width.
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = 525;

    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'top'    => __( 'Top Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
        'social' => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
        'account' => __( 'Login Register', 'twentyseventeen' ),
    ) );

    /*
     * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
     * to output valid HTML5.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'comment-form',
        'comment-list',
        'gallery',
        'caption',
    ) );

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Formats.
     *
     * See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
        'aside',
        'image',
        'video',
        'quote',
        'link',
        'gallery',
        'audio',
    ) );

    // Add theme support for Custom Logo.
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'width'       => 250,
        'height'      => 250,
        'flex-width'  => true,
    ) );

    // Add theme support for selective refresh for widgets.
    add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );

    /*
     * This theme styles the visual editor to resemble the theme style,
     * specifically font, colors, and column width.
     */
    add_editor_style( array( 'assets/css/editor-style.css', twentyseventeen_fonts_url() ) );

    // Define and register starter content to showcase the theme on new sites.
    $starter_content = array(
        'widgets' => array(
            // Place three core-defined widgets in the sidebar area.
            'sidebar-1' => array(
                'text_business_info',
                'search',
                'text_about',
            ),

            // Add the core-defined business info widget to the footer 1 area.
            'sidebar-2' => array(
                'text_business_info',
            ),

            // Put two core-defined widgets in the footer 2 area.
            'sidebar-3' => array(
                'text_about',
                'search',
            ),
        ),

        // Specify the core-defined pages to create and add custom thumbnails to some of them.
        'posts' => array(
            'home',
            'about' => array(
                'thumbnail' => '{{image-sandwich}}',
            ),
            'contact' => array(
                'thumbnail' => '{{image-espresso}}',
            ),
            'blog' => array(
                'thumbnail' => '{{image-coffee}}',
            ),
            'homepage-section' => array(
                'thumbnail' => '{{image-espresso}}',
            ),
        ),

        // Create the custom image attachments used as post thumbnails for pages.
        'attachments' => array(
            'image-espresso' => array(
                'post_title' => _x( 'Espresso', 'Theme starter content', 'twentyseventeen' ),
                'file' => 'assets/images/espresso.jpg', // URL relative to the template directory.
            ),
            'image-sandwich' => array(
                'post_title' => _x( 'Sandwich', 'Theme starter content', 'twentyseventeen' ),
                'file' => 'assets/images/sandwich.jpg',
            ),
            'image-coffee' => array(
                'post_title' => _x( 'Coffee', 'Theme starter content', 'twentyseventeen' ),
                'file' => 'assets/images/coffee.jpg',
            ),
        ),

        // Default to a static front page and assign the front and posts pages.
        'options' => array(
            'show_on_front' => 'page',
            'page_on_front' => '{{home}}',
            'page_for_posts' => '{{blog}}',
        ),

        // Set the front page section theme mods to the IDs of the core-registered pages.
        'theme_mods' => array(
            'panel_1' => '{{homepage-section}}',
            'panel_2' => '{{about}}',
            'panel_3' => '{{blog}}',
            'panel_4' => '{{contact}}',
        ),

        // Set up nav menus for each of the two areas registered in the theme.
        'nav_menus' => array(
            // Assign a menu to the "top" location.
            'top' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Top Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
                'items' => array(
                    'link_home', // Note that the core "home" page is actually a link in case a static front page is not used.
                    'page_about',
                    'page_blog',
                    'page_contact',
                ),
            ),

            // Assign a menu to the "social" location.
            'social' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
                'items' => array(
                    'link_yelp',
                    'link_facebook',
                    'link_twitter',
                    'link_instagram',
                    'link_email',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    /**
     * Filters Twenty Seventeen array of starter content.
     *
     * @since Twenty Seventeen 1.1
     *
     * @param array $starter_content Array of starter content.
     */
    $starter_content = apply_filters( 'twentyseventeen_starter_content', $starter_content );

    add_theme_support( 'starter-content', $starter_content );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentyseventeen_setup' );

add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}

add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');
```

Comment: are you using gateway plugin?

Comment: Not i'm using Woocommerce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello after reading your code i have found that `add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');` creating problem . Just remove this line or comment this from your code and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks Hasan !!

Its Working Fine.